# Python pandas insert list into a cell

Tags: python, list, pandas, insert, dataframe

I have a list 'abc' and a dataframe 'df':

```
abc = ['foo', 'bar']
df =
    A  B
0  12  NaN
1  23  NaN
```

I want to insert the list into cell 1B, so I want this result:

```
    A  B
0  12  NaN
1  23  ['foo', 'bar']
```

Ho can I do that?

1) If I use this:

```
df.ix[1,'B'] = abc
```

I get the following error message:

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

because it tries to insert the list (that has two elements) into a row / column but not into a cell.

2) If I use this:

```
df.ix[1,'B'] = [abc]
```

then it inserts a list that has only one element that is the 'abc' list ( `[['foo', 'bar']]` ).

3) If I use this:

```
df.ix[1,'B'] = ', '.join(abc)
```

then it inserts a string: ( `foo, bar` ) but not a list.

4) If I use this:

```
df.ix[1,'B'] = [', '.join(abc)]
```

then it inserts a list but it has only one element ( `['foo, bar']` ) but not two as I want ( `['foo', 'bar']` ).

Thanks for help!

---

### EDIT

My new dataframe and the old list:

```
abc = ['foo', 'bar']
df2 =
    A    B         C
0  12  NaN      'bla'
1  23  NaN  'bla bla'
```

Another dataframe:

```
df3 =
    A    B         C                    D
0  12  NaN      'bla'  ['item1', 'item2']
1  23  NaN  'bla bla'        [11, 12, 13]
```

I want insert the 'abc' list into `df2.loc[1,'B']` and/or `df3.loc[1,'B']`.

If the dataframe has columns only with integer values and/or NaN values and/or list values then inserting a list into a cell works perfectly. If the dataframe has columns only with string values and/or NaN values and/or list values then inserting a list into a cell works perfectly. But if the dataframe has columns with integer and string values and other columns then the error message appears if I use this: `df2.loc[1,'B'] = abc` or `df3.loc[1,'B'] = abc`.

Another dataframe:

```
df4 =
          A     B
0      'bla'  NaN
1  'bla bla'  NaN
```

These inserts work perfectly: `df.loc[1,'B'] = abc` or `df4.loc[1,'B'] = abc`.

Comment: What version pandas are you using? the following worked using pandas `0.15.0`: `df.loc[1,'b'] = ['foo','bar']`

Comment: Thank you! I use Python 2.7 and I tried pandas 0.14.0 and 0.15.0 and it worked with the test data above. But what if I have a 'C' column as well with some integer values? 'A' has strings. Having an integer column and a srting column I get the same error: ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Comment: You're going to have to post data and code to explain and show what you mean

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`df3.set_value(1, 'B', abc)` works for any dataframe. Take care of the data type of column 'B'. For example, a list can not be inserted into a float column, at that case `df['B'] = df['B'].astype(object)` can help.

Comment: Note that this command has been **deprecated**. There is an update right below.

Answer (score 205):

Since `set_value` has been [deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_value.html) since version 0.21.0, you should now use [`at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html). It can insert a list into a cell without raising a `ValueError` as `loc` does. I think this is because `at` *always* refers to a single value, while `loc` can refer to values as well as rows and columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': ['x', 'y', 'z']})

df.at[1, 'B'] = ['m', 'n']

df =
    A   B
0   1   x
1   2   [m, n]
2   3   z
```

You also need to make sure the *column* you are inserting into has `dtype=object`. For example

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [1,2,3]})
>>> df.dtypes
A    int64
B    int64
dtype: object

>>> df.at[1, 'B'] = [1, 2, 3]
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

>>> df['B'] = df['B'].astype('object')
>>> df.at[1, 'B'] = [1, 2, 3]
>>> df
   A          B
0  1          1
1  2  [1, 2, 3]
2  3          3
```

Comment: Very helpful, but what about when trying to set the list as a value in a new row of the dataframe? I want to iteratively add rows as the data is discovered. In the past I used `.loc` because it can add a new row, but it cannot store a list. `.at` can store a list, but not add a new row, so far as I can tell

Answer (score 63):

## Pandas >= 0.21

`set_value` has been deprecated.  **You can now use `DataFrame.at` to set by label, and `DataFrame.iat` to set by integer position.**

#### Setting Cell Values with [`at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html)/[`iat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html)

```
# Setup
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [12, 23], 'B': [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]})
>>> df

    A       B
0  12  [a, b]
1  23  [c, d]

>>> df.dtypes

A     int64
B    object
dtype: object
```

If you want to set a value in second row of the "B" column to some new list, use `DataFrame.at`:

```
>>> df.at[1, 'B'] = ['m', 'n']
>>> df

    A       B
0  12  [a, b]
1  23  [m, n]
```

You can also set by integer position using `DataFrame.iat`

```
>>> df.iat[1, df.columns.get_loc('B')] = ['m', 'n']
>>> df

    A       B
0  12  [a, b]
1  23  [m, n]
```

---

#### What if I get `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`?

I'll try to reproduce this with:

```
>>> df
    A   B
0  12 NaN
1  23 NaN

>>> df.dtypes
A      int64
B    float64
dtype: object
```

```
>>> df.at[1, 'B'] = ['m', 'n']
# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

This is because of a your object is of `float64` dtype, whereas lists are `object`s, so there's a mismatch there. What you would have to do in this situation is to convert the column to object first.

```
>>> df['B'] = df['B'].astype(object)
>>> df.dtypes

A     int64
B    object
dtype: object
```

Then, it works:

```
>>> df.at[1, 'B'] = ['m', 'n']
>>> df
    
    A       B
0  12     NaN
1  23  [m, n]
```

---

#### Possible, But Hacky

Even more wacky, I've found that you can hack through `DataFrame.loc` to achieve something similar if you pass nested lists.

```
>>> df.loc[1, 'B'] = [['m'], ['n'], ['o'], ['p']]
>>> df

    A             B
0  12        [a, b]
1  23  [m, n, o, p]
```

You can read more about why this works [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54447608/4909087)

Answer (score 8):

**Quick work around**

Simply enclose the list within a new list, as done for col2 in the data frame below. The reason it works is that python takes the outer list (of lists) and converts it into a column as if it were containing normal scalar items, which is lists in our case and not normal scalars.

```
mydict={'col1':[1,2,3],'col2':[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]}
data=pd.DataFrame(mydict)
data


   col1     col2
0   1       [1, 4]
1   2       [2, 5]
2   3       [3, 6]
```

Comment: I am getting empty lists in col2, even though I populated them

Answer (score 7):

Also getting

`ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable`,

using .at rather than .loc did not make any difference in my case, but enforcing the datatype of the dataframe column did the trick:

```
df['B'] = df['B'].astype(object)
```

Then I could set lists, numpy array and all sorts of things as single cell values in my dataframes.

Answer (score 2):

As mentionned in this post [pandas: how to store a list in a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133961/pandas-how-to-store-a-list-in-a-dataframe); the dtypes in the dataframe may influence the results, as well as calling a dataframe or not to be assigned to.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a solution that's pretty simple to implement.

Make a temporary class just to wrap the list object and later call the value from the class.

Here's a practical example:

1. Let's say you want to insert list object into the dataframe.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'a': 1},
    {'a': 2},
    {'a': 3},
])

df.loc[:, 'b'] = [
    [1,2,4,2,], 
    [1,2,], 
    [4,5,6]
] # This works. Because the list has the same length as the rows of the dataframe

df.loc[:, 'c'] = [1,2,4,5,3] # This does not work. 

>>> ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

## To force pandas to have list as value in each cell, wrap the list with a temporary class.

class Fake(object):
    def __init__(self, li_obj):
        self.obj = li_obj

df.loc[:, 'c'] = Fake([1,2,5,3,5,7,]) # This works. 

df.c = df.c.apply(lambda x: x.obj) # Now extract the value from the class. This works.
```

Creating a fake class to do this might look like a hassle but it can have some practical applications. For an example you can use this with `apply` when the return value is list.

Pandas would normally refuse to insert list into a cell but if you use this method, you can force the insert.

Comment: .apply is generally slow as it loops over each cell, so if you're going to loop anyway wouldn't it be easier to just create your new column and then loop over it, setting each cell to your list?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer [.at](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) and [.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html). It is important to note, that the target column needs a `dtype` (`object`), which can handle the list.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [0, 1, 2, 3],
    'B': np.array([np.nan]*3 + [[3, 33]], dtype=object),
    })
print('df to start with:', df, '\ndtypes:', df.dtypes, sep='\n')

df.at[0, 'B'] = [0, 100]  # at assigns single elemnt
df.loc[1, 'B'] = [[ [1, 11] ]]  # loc expects 2d input

print('df modified:', df, '\ndtypes:', df.dtypes, sep='\n')
```

**output**

```
df to start with:
   A        B
0  0      NaN
1  1      NaN
2  2      NaN
3  3  [3, 33]

dtypes:
A     int64
B    object
dtype: object
df modified:
   A          B
0  0   [0, 100]
1  1  [[1, 11]]
2  2        NaN
3  3    [3, 33]

dtypes:
A     int64
B    object
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

first set the cell to blank.  next use at to assign the abc list to the cell at 1, 'B'

```
abc = ['foo', 'bar']
df =pd.DataFrame({'A':[12,23],'B':[np.nan,np.nan]})
df.loc[1,'B']=''
df.at[1,'B']=abc
print(df)
```