# pandas: how to store a list in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to set a cell value as a list. Say for example:

```
df.loc['a']['b'] = ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

However, I'm unable to do so as I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

My dataframe currently is just all zeros and is nxn. Is there any way to be able to set the cell value so that when I execute `df.loc['a']['b']`, I get back `['one', 'two', 'three']`.

Comment: does `df.loc['a']['b'] = [['one', 'two', 'three']]` work?

Comment: As answered in the duplicate, one should make the column of `object` type, **and** one should use `at` instead of `loc`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem is that you likely have a dataframe where all the columns are series of type float or int. The solution is to change them type 'object.'

```
In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((4,4)))

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
     0    1    2    3
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0

In [5]: df.dtypes
Out[5]: 
0    float64
1    float64
2    float64
3    float64
dtype: object

In [6]: df = df.astype('object')

In [7]: df[1][2] = [1,2,3]

In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
   0          1  2  3
0  0          0  0  0
1  0          0  0  0
2  0  [1, 2, 3]  0  0
3  0          0  0  0
```

Comment: Couldnt you set the dtype on one column?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, I just need to do one colum as Merlin mentions

Answer (score 6):

This is a tortured way of doing it.  I really hope someone has a better answer.

```
df.loc[['a'], ['b']] = df.loc[['a'], ['b']].applymap(lambda x: ['one', 'two', 'three'])
```

Comment: Good solution. Keeping it on bookmark :)