# pandas apply when cells contain lists

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-apply

I have a `DataFrame` where one column contains lists as cell contents, something like following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col_lists': [[1, 2, 3], [5]],
    'col_normal': [8, 9]
})

>>> df
   col_lists  col_normal
0  [1, 2, 3]           8
1        [5]           9
```

I would like to apply some transformation to each element of `col_lists`, for example:

```
df['col_lists'] = df.apply(
    lambda row: [ None if (element % 2 == 0) else element for element in row['col_lists'] ], 
    axis=1
)

>>> df
      col_lists  col_normal
0  [1, None, 3]           8
1           [5]           9
```

With this dataframe this works as I expect, however, when I apply the same code to other dataframe I am getting a bizarre result -- for each row, the column contains only first element of the list:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'col_lists': [[1, 2], [5]], # length of first list is smaller here
    'col_normal': [8, 9]
})

df2['col_lists'] = df2.apply(
    lambda row: [ None if (element % 2 == 0) else element for element in row['col_lists'] ], 
    axis=1
)

>>> df2
   col_lists  col_normal
0        1.0           8
1        5.0           9
```

I have two questions:

(1) What is going on here? Why I am getting a correct result in case of `df`, but not `df2`?

(2) How can I correctly apply some transformations to lists within a `DataFrame`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, df2 looks as

 `col_lists  col_normal
0  [1, None]           8
1        [5]           9`
 
to me.

Comment: What is your desired out put? I get the same format for df2 and df. For df2 top row i get `[1, None, 3]` using your code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I think working with `list`s in pandas is not [good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52563718/2901002).

But if really need it, try upgrade pandas, because for me it working nice in `pandas 0.23.4`:

```
df2['col_lists'] = df2.apply(
    lambda row: [ None if (element % 2 == 0) else element for element in row['col_lists'] ], 
    axis=1
)

print (df2)
   col_lists  col_normal
0  [1, None]           8
1        [5]           9
```

Comment: thanks! I had `pandas` version `0.22.0`, upgrading it solved the problem