# python - how to delete duplicate list in each row (pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a list contained in each row and I would like to delete duplicated element by keeping the highest value from a score.

here is my data from data frame df1

```
        pair    score
0   [A , A ]    1.0000
1   [A , F ]    0.9990
2   [A , G ]    0.9985
3   [A , G ]    0.9975
4   [A , H ]    0.9985
5   [A , H ]    0.9990
```

I would like to see the result as

```
            pair    score
    0   [A , A ]    1.0000
    1   [A , F ]    0.9990
    2   [A , G ]    0.9985
    4   [A , H ]    0.9990
```

I have tried to use group by and set a score = max, but it's not working

Comment: Lists aren’t hashable, so you can’t group by them. Try making them tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I think working with `list`s in pandas is not [good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52563718/2901002).

Solution working if convert lists to helper column with tuples - then [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df['new'] = df.pair.apply(tuple)
df = df.sort_values('score', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('new')
print (df)
     pair   score     new
0  [A, A]  1.0000  (A, A)
1  [A, F]  0.9990  (A, F)
5  [A, H]  0.9990  (A, H)
2  [A, G]  0.9985  (A, G)
```

Or to 2 new columns:

```
df[['a', 'b']] = pd.DataFrame(df.pair.values.tolist())
df = df.sort_values('score', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['a', 'b'])
print (df)
     pair   score  a  b
0  [A, A]  1.0000  A  A
1  [A, F]  0.9990  A  F
5  [A, H]  0.9990  A  H
2  [A, G]  0.9985  A  G
```

Answer (score 0):

Make new column `pair2` with sorted values of string type and then drop duplicates
Will handle if pair have value `[A,G]` and `[G,A]` treating them same

```
df['pair2']=df.pair.map(sorted).astype(str)
df.sort_values('score',ascending=False).drop_duplicates('pair2',keep='first').drop('pair2',axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Ouput:

```
pair    score
[A, A]  1.0000
[A, F]  0.9990
[A, H]  0.9990
[A, G]  0.9985
```