# pandas group several columns by one

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
Id    1    2    3    4

z1    3    0    2    2 
z1    1    4    4    3
z2    8    1    7    9
z2    0    0    2    3
z2    5    6    7    9
z3    0    5    6    2
z3    4    4    8    2
```

Here is my data, I want to group every column into lists by Id, result should be this

```
Id    1      2      3      4

z1   [3,1]  [0,4]  [2,4]  [2,3]
z2 [8,0,5][1,0,6][7,2,7][9,3,9]
z3   [0,4]  [5,4]  [6,8]  [2,2]
```

So here is the thing I could do every column separately but I've done that and now I need to optimize this, is there any way for this to be done once for every column?? If not, maybe there is a way that works faster than pandas.groupby??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I think working with `list`s in pandas is not [good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52563718/2901002).

But if really need it, it is possible by [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with `list`:

```
df = df.groupby('Id').agg(list)
print (df)
            1          2          3          4
Id                                            
z1     [3, 1]     [0, 4]     [2, 4]     [2, 3]
z2  [8, 0, 5]  [1, 0, 6]  [7, 2, 7]  [9, 3, 9]
z3     [0, 4]     [5, 4]     [6, 8]     [2, 2]
```

Comment: why is it a bad idea?? also can you point me in the right direction if it's no good??

Comment: @Mels Hakobyan You can check link in answer. But all depends what you need. If small DataFrame to 1k rows it working nice. But problem is if large 100k+ rows DataFrame, it working, but next processing is obviously slow. But if performance is not important, then use solution with no problem. It is explined better now?

Comment: sure, thank you, the performance is crutial in this case, I try to minimize running time as much as possible

Comment: is it possible for your code to run longer then if I grouped every column separately, cuz currently that's what I get.

Comment: @MelsHakobyan - What is size of input DataFrame? What size of output? What is number of rows?

Comment: (4000000, 4) size of output is (5000, 4)