# pandas, good to have list as element or, just flatten it?

Tags: pandas

Suppose, I want to analyze item-purchase records

My analization function expects userid, item_ids

```
df analyze(user_id, item_ids):
   ..
```

Is it a good idea to prepare data in

```
user_id item_ids
1,  [3,4,5]
```

vs

```
user_id, item_ids
1,  3
1,  4
1,  5
```

(with the 2nd one, I could do groupby and generate the data format I need)

I just find it hard to work with data format of (`[1, [3,4,5]]`) than (`[1,3],[1,4],[1,5]`) in intermediate steps..

Comment: Second is winner, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/993984)

Comment: And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52563718)

Comment: but in my opinion it depends, if small data and need lists, it is up to you.