# Concat dataframes by matching a value in a column to a list in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 data frames with the following format:

```
    df1

    ID                     age
    [111, 222, 333]        15
    [444]                  9
    [555, 666, 777, 888]   8


    df2

    ID                school
    222               A
    777               B
```

I need to concat them by matching the IDs to get the following result

```
    df1_ID                 age   df2_ID   school 
    [111, 222, 333]        15    222      A
    [555, 666, 777, 888]   8     777      B
```

df1_ID could be a list of up to 10 IDs and I can't think of a way to concat the data frames efficiently. How would you approach this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If want working with data efficiently, is necessary change format, because working with `list`s in pandas is obviously [slow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52563718/2901002).

```
from itertools import chain

df11 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID' : list(chain.from_iterable(df1['ID'].tolist())), 
    'age' : df1['age'].values.repeat(df1['ID'].str.len())
})

print (df11)
    ID  age
0  111   15
1  222   15
2  333   15
3  444    9
4  555    8
5  666    8
6  777    8
7  888    8

df12 = df11.merge(df2, on='ID', how='left')
print (df12)
    ID  age school
0  111   15    NaN
1  222   15      A
2  333   15    NaN
3  444    9    NaN
4  555    8    NaN
5  666    8    NaN
6  777    8      B
7  888    8    NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Following you advice, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53218931) with further detail on unnesting data frames before merging.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df3 = df1.apply(lambda x: x if set(x[0]).intersection(set(df2['ID'])) else None, axis = 1)
df3 = df3.dropna().set_index('ID')
df3.reset_index(inplace = True)
final_df = pd.concat([df3, df2], axis = 1)
```

Comment: `way to concat the data frames efficiently` - can you add some timings?