# change all pandas dataframe cell in a column with an array

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy

I have a pandas Dataframe like as follow:

```py
                   column1         column2
0                     0               0
1                     0               0
2                     0               0
3                     0               0
...                  ...             ...
```

I would like to change all data in `column2` with

```py
a = numpy.zeros([16,16,16])
```

so the dataframe will look like

```py
                   column1         column2
0                     0           [[[0,0,0,....
1                     0           [[[0,0,0,....
2                     0           [[[0,0,0,....
3                     0           [[[0,0,0,....
...                  ...             ...
```

Comment: df['col'] = [np.zeros([16,16,16])]*len(df)

Comment: Why would you want to do so in the first place? You might aswell keep the numpy array as such and just index it accordingly as you'd also do with the dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I think working with `list`s or `array`'s this way in pandas is not [good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52563718/2901002).

But it is possible:

```
df['column2'] = [a for _ in df.index]
```

Comment: Thank you, I was using my an old data frame that uses that format exactly, changing everything is quite a hassle, so I rather just change using that format.