# how to split a list of values in one column of a dataframe into various columns equally

Tags: python, pandas

say i have a dataframe:

```
              x

0     [0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5]
1     [5.5, 6.5, 7.5]
2     [8.5, 9.5, 10.5, 11.5]
3     [12.5, 13.5, 14.5, 15.5]
```

and i want to split the values to three separate columns(each column with two values each) as:

```
              a             b            c 

0      [0.5, 1.5]      [2.5, 3.5]      [4.5]
1      [5.5, 6.5]      [7.5]             0
2      [8.5, 9.5]      [10.5, 11.5]      0
3      [12.5, 13.5]    [14.5, 15.5]      0
```

how do i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not mentioned if c will have anything after fourth element or just next two in case the list has more than six elements.

This is the code if you want everything after fourth element in c

```
df['a']=df['x'].apply(lambda x:x[:2] if len(x)>0 else 0)
df['b']=df['x'].apply(lambda x:x[2:4] if len(x)>2 else 0)
df['c']=df['x'].apply(lambda x:x[4:] if len(x)>4 else 0)
df.drop('x',axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Or, 
This is the code if you want two element in c even if the list has more after fourth element

```
df['a']=df['x'].apply(lambda x:x[:2] if len(x)>0 else 0)
df['b']=df['x'].apply(lambda x:x[2:4] if len(x)>2 else 0)
df['c']=df['x'].apply(lambda x:x[4:6] if len(x)>4 else 0)
df.drop('x',axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

First I think working with `list`s in pandas is not [good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52563718/2901002).

But possible, use list comprehension wit custom function and `DataFrame` constructor:

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/312464/2901002
def chunks(l, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from l."""
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]


df1 = pd.DataFrame([list(chunks(x, 2)) for x in df['x']]).fillna(0)
print (df1)
              0             1      2
0    [0.5, 1.5]    [2.5, 3.5]  [4.5]
1    [5.5, 6.5]         [7.5]      0
2    [8.5, 9.5]  [10.5, 11.5]      0
3  [12.5, 13.5]  [14.5, 15.5]      0
```