# Check reference list in pandas column using numpy vectorization

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a reference list

```
ref = ['September', 'August', 'July', 'June', 'May', 'April', 'March']
```

And a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Month_List': [['July'], ['August'], ['July', 'June'], ['May', 'April', 'March']]})
df
    Month_List
0   [July]
1   [August]
2   [July, June]
3   [May, April, March]
```

I want to check which elements from reference list is present in each row, and convert into binary list

I can achieve this using `apply`

```
def convert_month_to_binary(ref,lst):
    s = pd.Series(ref)
    return s.isin(lst).astype(int).tolist()  

df['Binary_Month_List'] = df['Month_List'].apply(lambda x: convert_month_to_binary(ref, x))
df

    Month_List          Binary_Month_List
0   [July]              [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1   [August]            [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2   [July, June]        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
3   [May, April, March] [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

However, using `apply` on large datasets is very slow and hence I am looking to use numpy vectorization. How can I improve my performance?

**Extension**:

I wanted to use `numpy vectorization` because I need to now apply another function on this list

I am trying like this, but performance is very slow. Similar results with `apply`

```
def count_one(lst):
    index = [i for i, e in enumerate(lst) if e != 0] 
    return len(index)

vfunc = np.vectorize(count_one)
df['Value'] = vfunc(df['Binary_Month_List'])
```

Comment: FYI - Vectorization works on a case by case basis. There's no magic function that works in all scenarios, if you are looking for one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In pandas is better [not use `list`s this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52563718/2901002), but it is possible with  [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) and [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for added missing categories, last convert values to numpy array and then to `list`s if performance is important:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df1 = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['Month_List']),columns=mlb.classes_)
df['Binary_Month_List'] = df1.reindex(columns=ref, fill_value=0).values.tolist()
```

Or with [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html), [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) and `reindex`:

```
df['Binary_Month_List'] = (df['Month_List'].str.join('|')
                                           .str.get_dummies()
                                           .reindex(columns=ref, fill_value=0)
                                           .values
                                           .tolist())
print (df)
            Month_List      Binary_Month_List
0               [July]  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1             [August]  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2         [July, June]  [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
3  [May, April, March]  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Performance is different:

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

In [338]: %timeit (df['Month_List'].str.join('|').str.get_dummies().reindex(columns=ref, fill_value=0).values.tolist())
31.4 ms ± 1.41 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [339]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['Month_List']),columns=mlb.classes_).reindex(columns=ref, fill_value=0).values.tolist()
5.57 ms ± 94.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [340]: %timeit df['Binary_Month_List2'] =df.Month_List.explode().str.get_dummies().sum(level=0).reindex(columns=ref, fill_value=0).values.tolist()
58.6 ms ± 461 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: how can I use vectorization ?

Answer (score 10):

We can using `explode` with `get_dummies`, notice `explode` is available after 0.25

```
df.Month_List.explode().str.get_dummies().sum(level=0).reindex(columns=ref, fill_value=0).values.tolist()
Out[79]: 
[[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]]

#df['new']=df.Month_List.explode().str.get_dummies().sum(level=0).reindex(columns=ref, fill_value=0).values.tolist()
```

Comment: I am getting this error - `'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'`

Comment: @Hardikgupta "notice `explode` is available after **0.25** "

Comment: if we have to use numpy vectorization, how can we achieve it? because I want to now apply another function to each list (which is in series)

Answer (score 4):

Here's one with NumPy tools -

```
def isin_lists(df_col, ref):
    a = np.concatenate(df_col)
    b = np.asarray(ref)

    sidx = b.argsort()
    c = sidx[np.searchsorted(b,a,sorter=sidx)]

    l = np.array([len(i) for i in df_col])
    r = np.repeat(np.arange(len(l)),l)

    out = np.zeros((len(l),len(b)), dtype=bool)
    out[r,c] = 1
    return out.view('i1')
```

Output for given sample -

```
In [79]: bin_ar = isin_lists(df['Month_List'], ref)

In [80]: bin_ar
Out[80]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=int8)

# To assign as lists for each row into `df`
In [81]: df['Binary_Month_List'] = bin_ar.tolist()

# To get counts
In [82]: df['Value'] = bin_ar.sum(1)

In [83]: df
Out[83]: 
            Month_List      Binary_Month_List  Value
0               [July]  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]      1
1             [August]  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]      1
2         [July, June]  [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]      2
3  [May, April, March]  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]      3
```

If you can't use the intermediate `bin_ar` for some reason and have only `'Binary_Month_List'` header to work with -

```
In [15]: df['Value'] = np.vstack(df['Binary_Month_List']).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: I cannot use sum directly, as there are more steps in that functions. Just for this example I am calculating count of 1's

Comment: @Hardikgupta Got it. Edited post.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will be faster. But [count-vector](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) can also be used in this case.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vect=CountVectorizer(binary=True)

mys=([(','.join(i)) for i in df['Month_List']])
X=vect.fit_transform(mys)
col_names=vect.get_feature_names()
ndf=pd.SparseDataFrame(X, columns=col_names)
df=df.join(ndf).astype(str)
df['Binary_Month_List'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].values.tolist()
```