# Apply a function to series of list without apply in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Binary_List': [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                                   [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                                   [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]]})
df

    Binary_List
0   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1   [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2   [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
3   [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

I want to apply a function to each list, without use of `apply` because `apply` is very slow when  running on large dataset

```
def count_one(lst):
    index = [i for i, e in enumerate(lst) if e != 0]
    # some more steps 
    return len(index)

df['Value'] = df['Binary_List'].apply(lambda x: count_one(x))
df

    Binary_List             Value
0   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]   1
1   [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]   1
2   [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]   2
3   [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]   3
```

I tried using this, but no improvement

```
vfunc = np.vectorize(count_one)
df['Value'] = vfunc(df['Binary_List'])
```

This gives me error

```
df['Value'] = count_one(df['Binary_List'])
```

Comment: You cant because you're storing an `object` in a DataFrame. If you instead just stored each element as its own cell this is a trivial and extremely fast `df.sum(1)`

Comment: Assuming it's for your previous question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/58136267/. Use the intermediate output from the posted answers, where you had the binary array output and sum along cols - `.sum(axis=1)`.

Comment: @Divakar - I cannot use sum directly, as I have pointed out, there are more steps in that functions. Just for example I am calculating count of 1's

Comment: Guess you would need stacking and summing : `np.vstack(df['Binary_Month_List']).sum(1)`.

Comment: As long as you have a list of lists, the `apply` or other action has to run a interpreted Python speed.  To get fast `numpy` speed it has to be a numeric 2d array.

Comment: @Divakar, this is not just about counting 1's, but applying a function without using `apply`.

Comment: As I said in the previous Q&A, there's no magic function.

Comment: agreed, but don't at least downvote the question

Comment: That's not from me.

Comment: As far as I know, downvotes (and up) are anonymous.  I suspect most downvoters don't stay around to follow the comments.

Comment: `df['Binary_List'].map(sum)` ?

Comment: What's the difference between dataframe `apply` and `map`?  I doubt if either converts the function or `lambda` to compiled code.  Calling the function once per row is the real time consumer, especially if the function is complex.  The iteration mechanism itself is usually a minor part of the time cost.

Answer (score 1):

for getting length of list items you can use str function like below

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Binary_List': [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                                   [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                                   [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]]})

df["Binary_List"].astype(np.str).str.count("1")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try [DataFrame.explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df.explode('Binary_List').reset_index().groupby('index').sum()

        Binary_List
index   
0        1
1        1
2        2
3        3
```

Also you can do:

```
pd.Series([np.array(key).sum() for key in df['Binary_List']])
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    3
dtype: int64
```