# Alternate to apply in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe like this

```
dat = [['ID1', '[1, 0, 1, 0, 0]'], ['ID2', '[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]'], ['ID3', '[1, 0, 1, 1, 0]']]
df = pd.DataFrame(dat, columns = ['ID', 'Values'])
df

    ID    Values
0   ID1   [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
1   ID2   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
2   ID3   [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

I want to calculate cumulative sum of each list, and store in new column. After this I want to take dot product of two list

```
df['Values'] = df['Values'].apply(lambda x : ast.literal_eval(x)) # Convert string into list type
df['Cumsum_Values'] = df['Values'].apply(lambda x : np.cumsum(x)) # cumulative sum of each list
df['Dot_Values'] = df.apply(lambda x : np.dot(x.Values, x.Cumsum_Values)) # dot product of columns Values and Cumsum_Values
df

    ID  Values            Cumsum_Values     Dot_Values
0   ID1 [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]   [1, 1, 2, 2, 2]   3
1   ID2 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]   [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]   1
2   ID3 [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]   [1, 1, 2, 3, 3]   6
```

By using `pandas` `apply`, I am able to do the task. However my records are in millions, and some of these operations are taking lot of time (>10mins).

Is there any alternative to make this processing fast?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-make-your-pandas-loop-71-803-times-faster-805030df4f06) can help.

Comment: @JohnDoe I believe he knows vectorization and built in functionalities are faster than `apply`, but this is exactly what he is asking: Is it possible to do it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I think working with `list`s in pandas is not [good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52563718/2901002).

One idea is working with numpy arrays if each list has same length,  so instead `dot` for each row multiple with `sum`:

```
import json

arr = np.array([json.loads(x) for x in df['Values']])
out = np.sum(arr * np.cumsum(arr, axis=1), axis=1)
print (out)
[3 1 6]

df['Dot_Values'] = out
print (df)
    ID           Values  Dot_Values
0  ID1  [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]           3
1  ID2  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]           1
2  ID3  [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]           6
```

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` is taking lot of time when used with millions of records

Comment: @HardikGupta - data are in file?

Comment: @HardikGupta - I am thinking if some another way for convert file to array, but not easy if more columns. But I try some tests.

Comment: I just have these two columns (ID, values) from the file, which is a csv

Comment: the first line processing is taking >10mins. Rest everything runs very fast because it's in array

Comment: @HardikGupta - Can you test `arr = np.array([json.loads(x) for x in df['Values']])` ?

Comment: `json.loads(x)` improved performance - ~2mins. Thank you so much

Comment: `json.loads()` is faster then, thanks i will keep in mind :)

Answer (score 2):

May be you can consider using a list comprehension rather than `apply`:

```
df['Cumsum_Values']=[np.cumsum(ast.literal_eval(i)) for i in df['Values']]
df['dot']=[np.dot(ast.literal_eval(a),b) for a,b in zip(df['Values'],df['Cumsum_Values'])]
```

---

```
    ID           Values    Cumsum_Values  dot
0  ID1  [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]  [1, 1, 2, 2, 2]    3
1  ID2  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]  [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]    1
2  ID3  [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]  [1, 1, 2, 3, 3]    6
```

Comparison:

[image]

Comment: Can you campare vectorized numpy solution?

Comment: @jezrael I am off my computer now. You can add that in your sol :) though i think there is a column missing in the solution

Comment: I think it would be a better idea to start the timing only *after* the creation of `df`, as it's not relevent to the comparison, and only add noise to it.

Comment: @Aryerez agreed:) i added it because of the ast literal eval would not work with timer loops if it didn't get fresh data. I would check what's the way of doing that when I am back. Can't test in mobile :)

Comment: @anky_91 I got that error too. Weird. Anyway, in my computer, the asker method was **1.47ms**, yours was **1.09ms**, and jezrael **626us**.

Comment: conversion using `ast.literal_eval` is taking a lot of time in the first line