# filter on pandas array

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm doing this kind of code to find if a value belongs to the array `a` inside a dataframe:

### Solution 1

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([{'a':[1,2,3], 'b':4},{'a':[5,6], 'b':7},])
df = df.explode('a')
df[df['a'] == 1]
```

will give the output:

```
    a   b
0   1   4
```

#### Problem

This can go worst if there are repetitions:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([{'a':[1,2,1,3], 'b':4},{'a':[5,6], 'b':7},])
df = df.explode('a')
df[df['a'] == 1]
```

will give the output:

```
    a   b
0   1   4
0   1   4
```

### Solution 2

Another solution could go like:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([{'a':[1,2,1,3], 'b':4},{'a':[5,6], 'b':7},])
df = df[df['a'].map(lambda row: 1 in row)]
```

#### Problem

That Lambda can't go fast if the Dataframe is Big.

### Question

As a first goal, I want all the lines where the value `1` belongs to `a`:

- without using Python, since it is slow
- with high performance
- avoiding memory issues
- ...

So I'm trying to understand what may I do with the arrays inside Pandas. Is there some documentation on how to use this type efficiently?

Comment: What are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you are trying to do:

```
df[df['a'].eq(1).groupby(level=0).transform('any')
```

Output:

```
   a  b
0  1  4
0  2  4
0  3  4
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong. This is normal behavior of `pandas.explode()`.

To check whether a value belongs to values in `a` you may use this:

`if x in df.a.explode()`

where  `x` is what you test for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can convert arrays to scalars with `DataFrame` constructor and then test value with [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
df = df[pd.DataFrame(df['a'].tolist()).eq(1).any(axis=1)]
print (df)
              a  b
0  [1, 2, 1, 3]  4
```

**Details**:

```
print (pd.DataFrame(df['a'].tolist()))
   0  1    2    3
0  1  2  1.0  3.0
1  5  6  NaN  NaN

print (pd.DataFrame(df['a'].tolist()).eq(1))
       0      1      2      3
0   True  False   True  False
1  False  False  False  False
```

> So I'm trying to understand what may I do with the arrays inside Pandas. Is there some documentation on how to use this type efficiently?

I think working with `list`s in pandas is not [good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52563718/2901002).