# pandas series.gt how use

Tags: python, pandas

data:

```
a=  [{"content": 1, "time": 1577870427}, {"content": 4, "time": 1577870427},
     {"content": 2, "time": 1577956827},
     {"content": 3, "time": 1580548827}, {"content": 5, "time": 1580635227},
     {"content": 6, "time": 1583054427}, {"content": 7, "time": 1583140827}]
```

i hope content more than 5

final data

```
[{"content": 6, "time": 1583054427}, {"content": 7, "time": 1583140827}]
```

my code

```
index = pd.to_datetime([i['time'] for i in a], unit='s')
df = pd.Series(a,index)
df.gt(5)
```

but raise error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in your Series are data in dictionaries, so in pandas is really not easy processing, also it is possible ony in loops (`apply` or `list comprehension` or `for`).

```
index = pd.to_datetime([i['time'] for i in a], unit='s')
df = pd.Series(a,index)
print (df.head().apply(type))
2020-01-01 09:20:27    <class 'dict'>
2020-01-01 09:20:27    <class 'dict'>
2020-01-02 09:20:27    <class 'dict'>
2020-02-01 09:20:27    <class 'dict'>
2020-02-02 09:20:27    <class 'dict'>
dtype: object
```

If want filter it is possible by extract `content` to `Series` with scalars and then possible compare:

```
print (df[df.str.get('content').gt(5)])
2020-03-01 09:20:27    {'content': 6, 'time': 1583054427}
2020-03-02 09:20:27    {'content': 7, 'time': 1583140827}
dtype: object
```

How it working:

```
print (df.str.get('content'))
2020-01-01 09:20:27    1
2020-01-01 09:20:27    4
2020-01-02 09:20:27    2
2020-02-01 09:20:27    3
2020-02-02 09:20:27    5
2020-03-01 09:20:27    6
2020-03-02 09:20:27    7
dtype: int64

print (df.str.get('content').gt(5))
2020-01-01 09:20:27    False
2020-01-01 09:20:27    False
2020-01-02 09:20:27    False
2020-02-01 09:20:27    False
2020-02-02 09:20:27    False
2020-03-01 09:20:27     True
2020-03-02 09:20:27     True
dtype: bool
```

If want processing data need `apply` with custom function:

```
def f(x):
    x['time'] = pd.to_datetime(x['time'], unit='s')
    return x

df = df.apply(f)
print (df)
2020-01-01 09:20:27    {'content': 1, 'time': 2020-01-01 09:20:27}
2020-01-01 09:20:27    {'content': 4, 'time': 2020-01-01 09:20:27}
2020-01-02 09:20:27    {'content': 2, 'time': 2020-01-02 09:20:27}
2020-02-01 09:20:27    {'content': 3, 'time': 2020-02-01 09:20:27}
2020-02-02 09:20:27    {'content': 5, 'time': 2020-02-02 09:20:27}
2020-03-01 09:20:27    {'content': 6, 'time': 2020-03-01 09:20:27}
2020-03-02 09:20:27    {'content': 7, 'time': 2020-03-02 09:20:27}
dtype: object
```

---

So better is create `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
print (df)
   content        time
0        1  1577870427
1        4  1577870427
2        2  1577956827
3        3  1580548827
4        5  1580635227
5        6  1583054427
6        7  1583140827
```

Then is easy processing, e.g. compare, because scalars:

```
print (df['content'].gt(5))
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
Name: content, dtype: bool
```

---

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s')
print (df)
   content                time
0        1 2020-01-01 09:20:27
1        4 2020-01-01 09:20:27
2        2 2020-01-02 09:20:27
3        3 2020-02-01 09:20:27
4        5 2020-02-02 09:20:27
5        6 2020-03-01 09:20:27
6        7 2020-03-02 09:20:27
```

Comment: but final data must be
```
[{"content": 6, "time": 1583054427}, {"content": 7, "time": 1583140827}]
```

Comment: @xin.chen - I know, but in pandas processing Series like `df = pd.Series(a,index)` is really complicated, because dicts.

Comment: actual ，my data is [{},{}],  can you use pands.series ?

Comment: @xin.chen - yop, it is possible, but data with dict, lists or similar are not easy processing, also it is slow, because pandas working fastest with arrays of scalars

Comment: @xin.chen - Answer is about lists, but same is possible say for list of dicts, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52563718/2901002)

Comment: @xin.chen - Added to answer how is possible convert datetimes in dict.