# Pandas: assign a list to all rows of a multi-index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a multi index dataframe, let's say

```
index = [['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'],[1, 2, 1, 2]]
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4], index=index)

     0
a 1  1
  2  2
b 1  3
  2  4
```

If I want to add a new column with a constant value, I can just do

```
df['new_col'] = 'IamNew'

     0 new_col
a 1  1  IamNew
  2  2  IamNew
b 1  3  IamNew
  2  4  IamNew
```

Perfect. 
However, what if I want to add a new column with a list? This doesn't work

```
df['new_col']=[1,2]
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

I have tried many options and spent quite some time trying to figure this out. 
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I think working with `list`s in pandas is not [good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52563718/2901002), but possible:

```
df['new_col']=pd.Series([[1,2]] * len(df), index=df.index)
print (df)
     0 new_col
a 1  1  [1, 2]
  2  2  [1, 2]
b 1  3  [1, 2]
  2  4  [1, 2]
```

Another solution:

```
df['new_col']= [[1,2]] * len(df)
```