# Replace a list value with another array in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am tring to replace a list value with another list value in a pandas but it raises an error : `cannot set using a multi-index selection indexer with a different length than the value`. Is it wrong practice to work with list values in pandas? Thank you

```
import pandas as pd

cars = {'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus','Audi A4'],
        'Price': [[123, 123123],[123, 123123],[123, 123123],[123, 123123]]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['Brand', 'Price'])
df[1, 'Price'] = [2342, 23423]

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[1, 'Price'] = [2342, 23423]

print(df)
0     Honda Civic  [123, 123123]
1  Toyota Corolla  [2342, 23423]
2      Ford Focus  [123, 123123]
3         Audi A4  [123, 123123]
```

> Is it wrong practice to work with list values in pandas?

I think working with `list`s in pandas is not [good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52563718/2901002), if possible create 2 columns here.

Answer (score 0):

You better create two columns of out your Price column like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns). But if you still have a good reason to have a list in the Price column and want to update it, use below code:

```
df.iloc[1, 1] = [2342, 23423]
```

This is integer-location based indexing for selection. 'Price' is in the index=1 position column wise.So, the 2nd 1 refers to 'Price' column and the 1st 1 refers to the actual row index.