# pandas column of list type

Tags: python, pandas

Need to generate a dataframe, column 'b' is of list type.

```
temp = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b')]


temp['a'] = 1
temp['b'] = [2,3]
```

expected result will be

```
a    b
1    [2,3]
```

but now the result is

```
a   b
NaN 2
NaN 3
```

How to get expected result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas: how to store a list in a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133961/pandas-how-to-store-a-list-in-a-dataframe)

Comment: `temp['b'] = [[2,3]]` & `temp['a'] = [1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You should add it row by row like this by loc[index]

```
import pandas as pd
temp = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b'])

temp.loc[0] = 2, [2,3]
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the values inside a bracket if the dataframe is empty.

```
import pandas as pd
temp = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b'])

temp['a'] = [1]
temp['b'] = [[2,3]]

print (temp)

temp['a'] = 5
temp['b'] = [[8,9]]

print (temp)
```

If the dataframe already had values, you can give a normal assignment.

First assignment to an empty dataframe will be:

```
   a       b
0  1  [2, 3]
```

Any further updates to the dataframe after the initial assignment will result in:

```
   a       b
0  5  [8, 9]
```

Alternatively as Tan suggested, you can use .loc or .iloc to store the values.

However, if you do initial assignment like this, then `a` will result in NaN as shown in example below (thx Trenton)

[image]

Comment: You may be correct. I am using an online version today and the pandas is `1.1.3`. Let me login to my home computer and check. Thx for confirmation

Comment: My example was an assignment after the initial value is set. Let me check on 1.2. I agree that the initial assignment will show NaN

Comment: In 1.2, after the initial assignment, it will result in 5, [8.9]. In 1.1.3 also, `a` will result in NaN for initial assignment.