# pandas extract list from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, preprocessor, data-cleaning

Suppose I have a dataframe like below:

```
        FDT_DATE    FFLT_LATITUDE   FFLT_LONGITUDE  FINT_STAT   FSTR_ID
51307   1417390467000   31.2899     121.4845    0   112609
51308   1417390428000   31.2910     121.4859    0   112609
51309   1417390608000   31.2944     121.4857    1   112609
51310   1417390548000   31.2940     121.4850    1   112609
51313   1417390668000   31.2954     121.4886    1   112609
51314   1417390717000   31.2965     121.4937    1   112609
53593   1417390758000   31.2946     121.4940    0   112609
63586   1417390798000   31.2932     121.4960    1   112609
63587   1417390818000   31.2940     121.4966    1   112609
63588   1417390827000   31.2946     121.4974    1   112609
63589   1417390907000   31.2952     121.4986    0   112609
```

I want to extract the location records in a polyline list, means to extract location of the records which have the same `FSTR_ID` and with the `FINT_STAT` equals to 1 :

```
    FSTR_ID    FDT_DATE    POLYLINE
0   112609    1417390608000 [[31.2944,121.4857],[31.2940,121.4850],[31.2954,121.4886],[31.2965,121.4937]]
1   112609    1417390798000 [[31.2932,121.4960],[31.2940,121.4966],[31.2946, 121.4974]]
```

How can I do that?

The orginal dataset can be generated by this code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"FDT_DATE":{"0":1417390467000,"1":1417390428000,"2":1417390608000,"3":1417390548000,"4":1417390668000,"5":1417390717000,"6":1417390758000,"7":1417390798000,"8":1417390818000,"9":1417390827000,"10":1417390907000},"FFLT_LATITUDE":{"0":31.2899,"1":31.291,"2":31.2944,"3":31.294,"4":31.2954,"5":31.2965,"6":31.2946,"7":31.2932,"8":31.294,"9":31.2946,"10":31.2952},"FFLT_LONGITUDE":{"0":121.4845,"1":121.4859,"2":121.4857,"3":121.485,"4":121.4886,"5":121.4937,"6":121.494,"7":121.496,"8":121.4966,"9":121.4974,"10":121.4986},"FINT_STAT":{"0":0,"1":0,"2":1,"3":1,"4":1,"5":1,"6":0,"7":1,"8":1,"9":1,"10":0},"FSTR_ID":{"0":112609,"1":112609,"2":112609,"3":112609,"4":112609,"5":112609,"6":112609,"7":112609,"8":112609,"9":112609,"10":112609}})
df = df.sort(['FDT_DATE'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483254/python-pandas-insert-list-into-a-cell) `list` into `pandas.DataFrame()` only with `.set_value()` method. And the column type should be `object`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"FDT_DATE":[1417390467000, 1417390428000, 1417390608000, 1417390548000,
    1417390668000, 1417390717000, 1417390758000, 1417390798000, 1417390818000,
    1417390827000, 1417390907000], "FFLT_LATITUDE":[31.2899, 31.291, 31.2944, 31.294,
    31.2954, 31.2965, 31.2946, 31.2932, 31.294, 31.2946, 31.2952],
    "FFLT_LONGITUDE":[121.4845, 121.4859, 121.4857, 121.485, 121.4886, 121.4937,
    121.494, 121.496, 121.4966, 121.4974, 121.4986],
    "FINT_STAT":[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    "FSTR_ID":[112609, 112609, 112609, 112609, 112609, 112609, 112609, 112609,
    112609, 112609, 112609]})

df = df.sort(['FDT_DATE']).reset_index(drop=True).reset_index()

def func(x):
    global a
    global b
    if (x['index'] - x['FINT_STAT']) != x['index']:
        return a
    else:
        b += 1
        a = b

# Create 't1' column for filter "1" groups in 'FINT_STAT' column
a = 0
b = 0
df['t1'] = df[['index', 'FINT_STAT']].apply(lambda x: func(x), axis=1)

# Initialize result dataframe
df_res = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['t1'])[['FSTR_ID', 'FDT_DATE', 't1']].copy()\
    .reset_index(drop=True)
df_res = df_res.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)

# First create 'POLYLINE' column then convert it into 'object'
df_res['POLYLINE'] = np.nan
df_res['POLYLINE'] = df_res['POLYLINE'].astype(object)

# Inserting list into dataframe is available with 'pd.DataFrame.set_value()
for i in df['t1'].dropna().unique():
    df_res.set_value(df_res.loc[df_res['t1'] == i, 't1'].index.tolist()[0], 'POLYLINE',
         df.loc[df['t1'] == i, ['FFLT_LATITUDE', 'FFLT_LONGITUDE']].values.tolist())

df_res = df_res.drop(['t1'], axis=1)
```

The result is (your posted result is NOT sorted by 'FDT_DATE'):

```
   FSTR_ID       FDT_DATE                                                                            POLYLINE
0   112609  1417390548000  [[31.294, 121.485], [31.2944, 121.4857], [31.2954, 121.4886], [31.2965, 121.4937]]
1   112609  1417390798000                       [[31.2932, 121.496], [31.294, 121.4966], [31.2946, 121.4974]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Initializing the data
df = pd.DataFrame({'FDT_DATE': {0: 1417390467000, 1: 1417390428000, 2: 1417390608000, 3: 1417390548000,
                                4: 1417390668000, 5: 1417390717000, 6: 1417390758000, 7: 1417390798000,
                                8: 1417390818000, 9: 1417390827000, 10: 1417390907000},
                   'FFLT_LATITUDE': {0: 31.2899, 1: 31.291, 2: 31.2944, 3: 31.294, 4: 31.2954,
                                     5: 31.2965, 6: 31.2946, 7: 31.2932, 8: 31.294, 9: 31.2946,
                                     10: 31.2952},
                   'FFLT_LONGITUDE': {0: 121.4845, 1: 121.4859, 2: 121.4857, 3: 121.485, 4: 121.4886,
                                      5: 121.4937, 6: 121.494, 7: 121.496, 8: 121.4966, 9: 121.4974,
                                      10: 121.4986},
                   'FINT_STAT': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 0, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1,
                                 10: 0},
                   'FSTR_ID': {0: 112609, 1: 112609, 2: 112609, 3: 112609, 4: 112609, 5: 112609,
                               6: 112609, 7: 112609, 8: 112609, 9: 112609, 10: 112609}})

# Transforming sequences of records with FINT_STAT == 1 to unique GROUP_ID values
df['GROUP_ID'] = df['FINT_STAT'].apply(np.logical_not).cumsum()
# Marking groups with FINT_STAT == 0 for removing
df['GROUP_ID'] *= df['FINT_STAT']
# Removing marked groups
df['GROUP_ID'] = df['GROUP_ID'].replace(0, np.NaN)

# Grouping by columns GROUP_ID and FSTR_ID
gb = df.groupby(['GROUP_ID', 'FSTR_ID'])

result = pd.DataFrame()
# Appending columns with values of minimal FDT_DATE for every group
result['MIN_FDT_DATE'] = gb['FDT_DATE'].min()
# Aggregating results by applying the lambda
# which return list of pairs of FFLT_LATITUDE and FFLT_LONGITUDE
result['COORDINATES'] = gb.apply(lambda group: [(row['FFLT_LATITUDE'], row['FFLT_LONGITUDE'])
                                 for _, row in group.iterrows()])


# Widening line and max column width for printing
pd.set_option('display.line_width', 300)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 200)
# Looking at result
print (result)
```

Output:

```
                   MIN_FDT_DATE                                                                         COORDINATES
GROUP_ID FSTR_ID                                                                                                   
2.0      112609   1417390548000  [(31.2944, 121.4857), (31.294, 121.485), (31.2954, 121.4886), (31.2965, 121.4937)]
3.0      112609   1417390798000                       [(31.2932, 121.496), (31.294, 121.4966), (31.2946, 121.4974)]
```

Comment: hi cridnirk, I think your method is more clear, but are there any way to keep the origin point's  FDT_DATE in the result ? Just like @ragesz did... I tried keep the FDT_DATE in groupby object but failed.