# Insert list into cells which meet column conditions

Tags: python, pandas

Consider `df`

```
   A  B  C
0  3  2  1
1  4  2  3
2  1  4  1
3  2  2  3
```

I want to add another column `"D"` such that D contains different Lists based on conditions on `"A"`, `"B"` and `"C"`

```
   A  B  C  D
0  3  2  1  [1,0]
1  4  2  3  [1,0]
2  1  4  1  [0,2]
3  2  2  3  [2,0]
```

My code snippet looks like:

```
df['D'] = 0
df['D'] = df['D'].astype(object)

df.loc[(df['A'] > 1) & (df['B'] > 1), "D"] = [1,0]
df.loc[(df['A'] == 1) , "D"] = [0,2]
df.loc[(df['A'] == 2) & (df['C'] != 0) , "D"] = [2,0]
```

When I try to run this code it throws the following error:

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

I have converted the column into `Object` type as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483254/python-pandas-insert-list-into-a-cell) but still with error.

What I can infer is that pandas is trying to iterate over the elements of the list and assigns each of those values to the cells where as I am trying to assign the entire list to all the cells meeting the criterion.

Is there any way I can assign lists in the above fashion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another solution is create `Series` filled by `list` with [`shape`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shape.html) for generating `length` of `df`:

```
df.loc[(df['A'] > 1) & (df['B'] > 1), "D"] = pd.Series([[1,0]]*df.shape[0])
df.loc[(df['A'] == 1) , "D"] = pd.Series([[0,2]]*df.shape[0])
df.loc[(df['A'] == 2) & (df['C'] != 0) , "D"] = pd.Series([[2,0]]*df.shape[0])
print (df)
   A  B  C       D
0  3  2  1  [1, 0]
1  4  2  3  [1, 0]
2  1  4  1  [0, 2]
3  2  2  3  [2, 0]
```

Comment: You can use `pd.Series([[1,0]], index=df.index)` if indices are arbitrary.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a goofy way to do it

```
cond1 = df.A.gt(1) & df.B.gt(1)
cond2 = df.A.eq(1)
cond3 = df.A.eq(2) & df.C.ne(0)

df['D'] = cond3.map({True: [2, 0]}) \
  .combine_first(cond2.map({True: [0, 2]})) \
  .combine_first(cond1.map({True: [1, 0]})) \

df
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer**: This is my own question.

Both the answers provided by [jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael) and [piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2336654/pirsquared) work.

I just wanted to add another way of doing it, albeit slightly different from the requirement I posted in the question. Instead of trying to insert a `list`, you can convert the `list` into a `string` and later access it by typecasting.

```
df.loc[(df['A'] > 1) & (df['B'] > 1), "D"] = '[1,0]'
df.loc[(df['A'] == 1) , "D"] = '[0,2]'
df.loc[(df['A'] == 2) & (df['C'] != 0) , "D"] = '[2,0]'
```

This may not be applicable to everyone's use, but I can definitely think of situations where this would suffice.