# Insert list in pandas dataframe cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a dictionary where each key has a list of values.
Length of the list associated with each key is different.
I want to convert the dictionary into a pandas dataframe with two columns 'Key' and 'Values'. Each row having one dictionary key in the 'Key' column and the list of values associated with it in 'Values' column. The dataframe will look as follows:

```
mapping_dict = {'A':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'B':['aa', 'bb', 'cc']}

df = 
    Key   Value
0   A     ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
1   B     ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
```

I tried using the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47548471/8966726) by modifying it as per my use case.
But it didn't output the required answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.Series` inside constructor, since dict values sizes are not equal, then `set_axis` to add column names  i.e

```
mapping_dict = {'A':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'B':['aa', 'bb', 'cc']}

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(mapping_dict).reset_index()).set_axis(['Key','Value'],1,inplace=False)

  Key         Value
0   A  [a, b, c, d]
1   B  [aa, bb, cc]
```

Option 2 , convert the dict items to list then pass it to constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(mapping_dict.items()),columns=['Key','Value'])
```

Comment: `TypeError: set_axis() got an unexpected keyword argument 'inplace'` when running your first code block with pandas                    2.0.3. (the second code block runs fine).

Answer (score 3):

If you pass a list, pandas considers it as several rows. However, you can trick it by placing your list as the single element of an outer list as bellow:

```
import pandas as pd
mapping_dict = {'A':[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']], 'B':[['aa', 'bb', 'cc']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(mapping_dict)
df

        A                 B
0   [a, b, c, d]    [aa, bb, cc]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it simply by using the "at" setter from pandas:

```
df.at[0,'A'] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

It works if column dtype is "object".

Answer (score 1):

I had to insert a list at a specific location and the following solution worked for me.

For some reason pandas doesn't complain when returning a list/array in an apply function so:

`df.loc[0,'A'] = df.loc[0,A].apply(lambda x: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])`

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have to update your dictionary beforehand then you can use [from_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html). Update to make your dictionary to make it a list of list.

```
import pandas as pd
mapping_dict = {'A':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'B':['aa', 'bb', 'cc']}
updated_dict = {k: [v] for k, v in mapping_dict.items()}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(updated_dict,orient='index')
```

If you want your exact formatting

```
df_formatted = df.reset_index()
df_formatted.columns = ['Key', 'Value']
print(df_formatted)

  Key         Value
0   B  [aa, bb, cc]
1   A  [a, b, c, d]
```

UPDATE

Bharath's answer is shorter but if you still want to use from_dict then you can take part of his method to do

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(list(mapping_dict.items()))
df2.columns = ['Key', 'Value']
```