# Error - unhashable type: 'list' when performing groupby using multi values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm pretty new to Python and I've been struggling to figure out how to solve the following error I started seeing in certain instances

```
for idKey, idKey_dataFrame in dataFrame[~pd.isna(dataFrame.idKey)].groupby("idKey", sort=False):

idKey_dataFrame = idKey_dataFrame[idKey_dataFrame.matched_customerProps.astype(str).str.contains("entitlement") & idKey_dataFrame.matched_customerProps.astype(str).str.contains("entitlement address")
]

for customer_type, idKey_sub_dataFrame in idKey_dataFrame.groupby("customer_type"):

    if customer_type != “repeat” and customer_type != “mvp”:
        continue

    self.log.info(f”Link made to {idKey}")
    idKey_csv_export = self.make_csv(idKey_sub_dataFrame, inventory=False)
```

I noticed that whenever I have more than 1 value, I get

> "ERROR - unhashable type: 'list'" error.

I'm not sure how to make it so I execute a groupby when there's multiple values and also perform a comparison against the object type.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

These are my columns

```
customer_name customer_id customer_type
xyz           003         repeat        
zzz           389         repeat, mvp, intl
yyy           002         repeat
yay           005         repeat
kdi           083         mvp, repeat
```

If I provide single valued customer_type, I get no error.  Whenever I test with customers that have more than 1 value under customer_type, I get an error.  The offending line is the first for statement ***for idKey, idKey_dataFrame in dataFrame[~pd.isna(dataFrame.idKey)***

Here is the complete error:

```
 ERROR - unhashable type: 'list' in line 258, in execute for customer_type, idKey_sub_dataFrame in idKey_dataFrame.groupby("customer_type"):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py", line 162, in get_iterator
    splitter = self._get_splitter(data, axis=axis)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py", line 168, in _get_splitter
    comp_ids, _, ngroups = self.group_info
  File "pandas/_libs/properties.pyx", line 34, in pandas._libs.properties.CachedProperty.__get__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py", line 296, in group_info
    comp_ids, obs_group_ids = self._get_compressed_labels()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py", line 312, in _get_compressed_labels
    all_labels = [ping.labels for ping in self.groupings]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py", line 312, in <listcomp>
    all_labels = [ping.labels for ping in self.groupings]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/grouper.py", line 397, in labels
    self._make_labels()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/grouper.py", line 421, in _make_labels
    labels, uniques = algorithms.factorize(self.grouper, sort=self.sort)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 208, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py", line 672, in factorize
    values, na_sentinel=na_sentinel, size_hint=size_hint, na_value=na_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py", line 508, in _factorize_array
    values, na_sentinel=na_sentinel, na_value=na_value
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1798, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.factorize
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1718, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable._unique
```

Comment: Without data or even any indication of what part throws that error it's difficult to help. My guess is that the column you are trying to groupby, either `idKey` or `customer_type` is a column that contains lists. That error is telling you that you cannot use lists, or any type that cannot be hashed, as a grouping column.

Comment: i dont see idKey in your dataset. Also you can't iterate through a DataFrame like so: `id, df in df.groupby()`: - which is probably what's raising the error.

Comment: Always share the entire error message, and a [mcve].

Comment: Updated with full error.

Comment: how have u managed to create a data frame column with type list?, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605085/insert-list-in-pandas-dataframe-cell, it's not trivial, anyway groupby try to hash the values of the column, see if you can convert your list to a string or a tuple or a set