# return is nan instead of Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nan

So I have this function:

```
def get_tag(word):
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(0, index=[1], columns=cols)
    df2 = df1
    df1 = get_freqs(word)
    L = df1.loc[1, :].idxmax()
    if df1.loc[1, L] > 0:
        df2.loc[1, L] = 1
    return df2
```

which returns a Series, as I expect it to :

```
wf.get_tag("email")
   City  CompanyName  Country   ...    MiddleName  State  Street
1     0            0        0   ...             1      0       0
[1 rows x 10 columns]
```

yet if I use it and assign the result to a cell of another series the value is nan:

```
word_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=WORD_FEATS)
...
word_df.loc[0, "TAGS"] = wf.get_tag(word)
```

By printing:

```
for l in list(word_df):
    print(l + ": " + str(word_df.loc[0, l]))
```

I get :

```
TAGS: nan
```

for any input.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Why do you think `wf.get_tag("email")` is a series? Looks like a shape `(1, 10)` *dataframe*. In addition, what is `word_df` and what is your desired output in `word_df`? Can you show us rather than describing? See also **[mcve]**.

Comment: Solved with dataframe.at
as here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483254/python-pandas-insert-list-into-a-cell

Comment: In general, you [shouldn't put lists in series](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373714/generic-dont-do-it-answer).

Comment: You can *want* anything you like. Just don't expect it to go as planned. Pandas stands for panel data, that means an X-Y grid of row labels and column labels. Just because putting arbitrary objects in series works doesn't mean it's a *good idea*.