# Inserting list into a cell - why does loc ACTUALLY work here?

Tags: python, pandas, list, indexing

We are aware that the standard method of setting a single cell is using `at` or `iat`. However, I noticed some interesting behaviour I was wondering if anyone could rationalise.

In solving [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483254/python-pandas-insert-list-into-a-cell/), I come across some weird behaviour of `loc`.

```
# Setup.

pd.__version__
# '0.24.0rc1'

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [12, 23], 'B': [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]})
df
    A       B
0  12  [a, b]
1  23  [c, d]
```

To set cell (1, 'B'), it suffices to do this with at, like `df.at[1, 'B'] = ...`. But with loc, I initially tried this, which did not work:

```
df.loc[1, 'B'] = ['m', 'n', 'o', 'p'] 
# ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

So, I tried (which also failed)

```
df.loc[1, 'B'] = [['m', 'n', 'o', 'p']]
# ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray
```

I thought `loc` would also somehow be able to take nested lists here. In a bizarre turn of events, *this* code worked:

```
df.loc[1, 'B'] = [['m'], ['n'], ['o'], ['p']]
df

    A             B
0  12        [a, b]
1  23  [m, n, o, p]
```

Why does `loc` work this way? Additionally, if you add another element to any of the lists, it flops:

```
df.loc[1, 'B'] = [['m'], ['n'], ['o'], ['p', 'q']]
# ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

Empty lists don't work either. It seems pointless to have to nest each element in its own list.

Why does `loc` do this? Is this documented behaviour, or a bug?

Comment: This looks to me like an unsupported feature, you could call it a bug or inconsistency, of course storing non-scalar types is ill-advised. Interesting that `.at` is less restrictive in it's usage

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This occurs because `loc` does a [*bunch*](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexing.py#L563-L620) of checking for all the many usecases which it supports. (Note: The history was that `loc` and `iloc` were created to remove ambiguity of `ix`, way back in 2013 v0.11, but even today there's still a lot of ambiguity in `loc`.)

In this case `df.loc[1, 'B']` can either return:

- a single element (as in this case, when there is a unique index/column for 1/'B').
- a Series (if EITHER one of the 1/'B' appears in index/columns multiple times).
- a DataFrame (if BOTH 1/'B' appear in index/columns multiple times).

*Aside: `iloc` suffers the same issue in this case, even though it's always going to be the first case, but that may be because loc and iloc share this assignment code.*

So that pandas needs to support all of those cases for assignment!

An early part of the assignment logic converts the list (of lists) into a numpy array:

```
In [11]: np.array(['m', 'n', 'o', 'p']).shape
Out[11]: (4,)

In [12]: np.array([['m', 'n', 'o', 'p']]).shape
Out[12]: (1, 4)
```

So you can't just pass the list of lists and expect to get the right array. Instead you could to explictly set into an object array:

```
In [13]: a = np.empty(1, dtype=object)

In [14]: a[0] = ['m', 'n', 'o', 'p']

In [15]: a
Out[15]: array([list(['m', 'n', 'o', 'p'])], dtype=object)
```

Now you can use this in the assignment:

```
In [16]: df.loc[0, 'B'] = a

In [17]: df
Out[17]:
    A             B
0  12  [m, n, o, p]
1  23        [c, d]
```

It's still not ideal, but to reiterate there are sooo many edge cases in `loc` and `iloc`, that the solution is to be as explicit as possible to avoid them (use `at` here). And more generally, as you know, avoid using lists inside a DataFrame!

Comment: Oh, I think I haven't answered the second part.

Comment: The answer to that is "it sneaks through" (the bunch of checks I link to). I'll try and amend this later with something more concrete.

Comment: So' "status-bydesign"? :D

Comment: @coldspeed status-by-duct-taped-together-working-well-enough :)