# Compare dictionary key value to multi-value index

Tags: python, pandas

I want to compare the following dictionary key:

```
{('F123', 1): 'R'}
```

To the index of the following dataframe ('F123', 1):

```
Connector Pin   Connector   Pin          Adj.         Color        
 F123      1        F123    1         [2, 6, 7]        NaN
```

If the dictionary key is equal to the dataframe index ('F123', 1) I want copy the dictionary value ('R') into the color column associated with the matching index. Both the dictionary and dataframe have a number of rows but for explanations sake I included only one of each. Speed doesn't matter as the data set is not big enough to matter.

```
if(df.index == dict.key()):
    df['Color'] = dict.value()
```

I am struggling syntactically on how to approach this problem.

update: I attempted this below (which I know is wrong). Still trying to nail down how to test all dict. keys one by one without hardcoding it in.

```
s = df.iterrows(pd.Series(dict.keys()))
df['Color'] = s
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a Series from the dictionary and then assign the Color column to that:

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
       Connector  Pin Connector.1 Pin.1 Adj.  Color
F123 1      F123    1         [2,    6,   7]    NaN

In [12]: s = pd.Series({('F123', 1): 'R'})

In [13]: df["Color"] = s

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
       Connector  Pin Connector.1 Pin.1 Adj. Color
F123 1      F123    1         [2,    6,   7]     R
```

Comment: So this works, but I am trying to do it for an entire list of different keys/indices. Instead of hard coding the dictionary key into the series is it possible to do some sort of iteration and go from top to bottom?

Comment: @MaxB if you have a larger dictionary `{('F123', 1): 'R', ('F456', 2): 'G'}` this will just work, no need for explicit iteration.

Comment: Could I please trouble you for a moment to have a look at this question? [Inserting list into a cell - why does loc ACTUALLY work here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54400137/inserting-list-into-a-cell-why-does-loc-actually-work-here) I have a feeling you might be able to weigh in here.