# Replace list based on column condition

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to edit a row in in my dataframe such as:

```
index columnA ColumnB
0     1       [a, b]
1     3       [c, b]
2     4       [a, b]
3     6       [d, a, b]
```

Lets say I want to replace the [c, b] with [q, y] where the columnA is value 3.
How would I go about doing that. I tried the following:

```
df.at[df['columnA'] == 3, 'ColumnB'] = [q, y]
```

Both are columns and I would like to edit the row based on the columnA value and not the index.

Comment: My answer here could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54399996/4909087

Comment: @coldspeed but those only work by index right?

Comment: So you can use `df.at[(df['columnA'] == 3).idxmax(), 'ColumnB'] = ['q', 'y']`

Comment: Thank you, idxmax() seems to make the difference

Comment: Sure, no problem. Please consider upvoting [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54399996/4909087) if it was helpful :-)