# Why does the content of a dataframe affect setting?

Tags: python, pandas

The outcome of this case:

```
df = _pd.DataFrame({'a':['1','2','3']})

df['b'] = _np.nan

for index in df.index:

    df.loc[index, 'b'] = [{'a':1}]
```

is:

```
    a   b
0   1   {'a': 1}
1   2   [{'a': 1}]
2   3   [{'a': 1}]
```

The outcome of this case:

```
df = _pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3]})

df['b'] = _np.nan

for index in df.index:

    df.loc[index, 'b'] = [{'a':1}]
```

is:

```
    a   b
0   1   {'a': 1}
1   2   {'a': 1}
2   3   {'a': 1}
```

Why?

```
_pd.__version__
'0.23.4'
```

Edit:  I want to add the version number, because this might be a bug.  That seems reasonable to me.  But, this new hold-your-hand system we have here at stackoverflow.com won't let me do it; hence I am adding this edit in order to meet the character requirement.

Comment: This is possibly a bug with `loc`, but in general if you are trying to assign a value to a single cell, you need to use `.at`: `df.at[index, 'b'] = [{'a':1}]` or `df.at[index, 'b'] = {'a':1}`, as appropriate.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54399996/4909087) for more info.

Comment: @coldspeed  As an aside, .at exhibits the same phenomenon.

Comment: `pandas` behaves really weirdly when assigning iterables to columns and to cells. I'd recommend against doing it every time.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is cause by the type transform when you assign `object` to a `float` type `columns`, the first item need to convert the whole columns type from float to object , then the whole `column` became `object` and the `index` number `1,2` will be the right type `assign` since the `column` itself already become `object`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['1','2','3']})
df['b'] = np.nan
df['b']=df['b'].astype(object)
for index in df.index:
    df.loc[index, 'b'] = [{'a':1}]
    print(df.loc[index, 'b'] ,index)

[{'a': 1}] 0
[{'a': 1}] 1
[{'a': 1}] 2
df
   a           b
0  1  [{'a': 1}]
1  2  [{'a': 1}]
2  3  [{'a': 1}]
```

Also , I think this may belong to the topic https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11617

Comment: I also believe the change in dtype is the reason for this.

Comment: @coldspeed still think this is bug :-)

Comment: @all Is this a bug?

Comment: @adpatter I think so