# Handling in DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas

```
CustomerNumber           TransactionDate
1                 [ 12/3/2019 12/4/2019 12/17/2019 ]
2                 [ 1/4/2019 4/4/2019]
3                 [ 7/5/2019]
4                 [ 7/5/2019 7/7/2019 9/5/2019 9/15/2019 10/15/2019]
```

Hi , I have This DataFrame TransactionDate(MM/DD/YYYY), I want to calculate the distance between 2 days in each sequence.
I want result :

```
CustomerNumber           TransactionDate
1                 [ 1 13 ]
2                 [ 3 ]
3                 [ 0 ]
4                 [ 2 60 10 30]
```

I am a beginner Data Analysis with Python. Pls help me ideal

Comment: Can you share the file from which you are reading the data? Please note, the list items in each row should be separated by ',' comma separator [ 1/4/2019, 4/4/2019], as if now the dates are separated by '  ' space [ 1/4/2019 4/4/2019] but it is not the python proper format. Please refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483254/python-pandas-insert-list-into-a-cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `datetime.timedelta` for this by converting each value in each row to a `datetime.datetime`, taking the difference of consecutive values and extracting the day value.

```
from datetime import datetime

date_format = '%m/%d/%Y'

def differencer(value):
    return [(datetime.strptime(second, date_format) - datetime.strptime(first, date_format)).days 
            for first, second in zip(value, value[1:])] or [0]

df['TransactionDate'].apply(differencer)
```

Output:

```
0            [1, 13]
1               [90]
2                [0]
3    [2, 60, 10, 30]
Name: TransactionDate, dtype: object
```

I realise it is slightly different from what is asked in the question, but I believe that is a mistake. I did add an `or [0]` to convert empty `lists`, though.

Comment: @TrinhPham You're welcome! Also, next time, please refrain from posting further clarifications as answers - edit your question or post comments instead.

Comment: Can you explain your code ? Because I want understand this code . Thank @gmds

Comment: @TrinhPham Is my explanation in the answer unclear?

Comment: Yes , I have learned Python a week ago , So I hope you explain more clearly

Comment: In that case, there would be too much to explain. I suggest you start by reading the [`datetime` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html).