# Preventing Broadcasting in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

We have code that stuffs an array into a dataframe (yes, I know, not exactly best practice).

`df.at[index,'alist'] = list(alist)`

`alist` is a list but broadcasting was preventing the operation, so the `list(alist)` was used to prevent the broadcasting and allow the operation.

With the last set of source library updates `list(alist)` started broadcasting, causing this line to fail with the error, `Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray`

Any thoughts on how to correct?

Comment: "Causing this line to fail" and what was the error you got?

Comment: You're assigning to a single cell, there's really no broadcasting going on here.

Comment: @cs95 thanks, question updated with error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`at` won't convert you `dtype` for you.  `loc` will but errors out because it assumes you are trying to push a list into multiple cells.

Convert your `dtype` then use `at`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(1, range(10), [*'ABC'])

df = df.astype({'A': object})

df.at[2, 'A'] = [1, 2, 3]

df

           A  B  C
0          1  1  1
1          1  1  1
2  [1, 2, 3]  1  1
3          1  1  1
4          1  1  1
5          1  1  1
6          1  1  1
7          1  1  1
8          1  1  1
9          1  1  1
​
```

Comment: [This was my suspicion as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54399996/4909087), but I would've imagined this would throw `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` Their error message seems to suggest otherwise, but I think a dtype=object conversion should fix it anyway.

Comment: @cs95 That's a target for this dup imo

Comment: Perhaps, maybe not. The fact that their error message is different from what our codes produce is still bothering me...