# Proper way to set a cell value when the value to set is multiple nested lists

Tags: python, pandas, nested-lists

Goal: To update a cell value of a pandas dataframe with a list of lists of lists

Problem: When attempting to do this, I get an error of "Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable"

Overview: I have a pandas dataframe, to which I am wanting to update a cell value. The cell value to input is a list, of lists of lists. The dataframe is already storing a cell value that is such, but this value needs to be updated to a new list of lists of lists. However, when I attempt to make the cell update, I receive the error noted above. I cannot reproduce this issue is some simplified code, so I wonder if it has to do with how long the list is - 40+ lists within lists.

My code to perform this action looks something like this, though as I said, this will not reproduce the issue, as I suspect it has to do with the length of the list:

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame(data={'First':['Bob','Bobby'], 'Last': ['Bobberson', 'Bobson']})

for i in df.index:
    df.loc[i, 'First'] = [[[1,3], [4,5]],[[2,3],[4,5]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `.loc` with `.at`:

```
for i in df.index:
    df.at[i, 'First'] = [[[1,3], [4,5]],[[2,3],[4,5]]]
```

See more details about why `.loc` has a problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483254/python-pandas-insert-list-into-a-cell)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!