# add a list into panda data frame cell

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/ymx19/Desktop/EHS/Location/results/Batch3_exclude_enterprise_wenran/first 100 - attribute/ABM.csv')
list_2 = ['a','b','c']
df.at[0, 'Attribute_consolidated'] = list_2
```

error code:
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

The goal is to add a list into pandas DataFrame cell.
I did a similar thing before and it worked, but somehow the code is no longer working in this case.

Comment: Use.`df.loc[0, 'Attribute_consolidated'] = list_2`

Comment: It shows another error: ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Comment: Per [the top voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47548471/15497888) you are correct `at` is the method to use for this operation, but the second requirement is that the column must be of dtype `object` or you'll receive a "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence"