# Python sets stored as string in a column of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe, where one column contains sets of strings (each row is a (single) set of strings). However, when I "save" this dataframe to csv, and read it back into a pandas dataframe later, each set of strings in this particular column seems to be saved as a single string. For example the value in this particular row, should be a single set of strings, but it seems to have been read in as a single string:

[image]

I need to access this data as a python set of strings, is there a way to turn this back into a set? Or better yet, have pandas read this back in as a set?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I wonder if you could do the same thing you can do with a list ( ie `df.at[1, 'B'] = {'m', 'n'}`), as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47548471/15038439

Comment: But I want to extract the set, not put a set into it.

Comment: Sorry about that, misread the question.

Comment: Use `eval` to parse and evaluate an object as a Python expression

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the string in the "set()" function to turn it back into a set.

```
string = "{'+-0-', '0---', '+0+-', '0-0-', '++++', '+++0', '+++-', '+---', '0+++', '0++0', '0+00', '+-+-', '000-', '+00-'}"
new_set = set(string)
```

Comment: The result of that code seems to be `{'+', ',', "'", '}', '0', ' ', '-', '{'}`

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a different separator while converting dataframe to csv.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(["{'Ramesh','Suresh','Sachin','Venkat'}"],columns=['set'])
print('Old df  \n', df)

df.to_csv('mycsv.csv', sep= ';', index=False)

new_df = pd.read_csv('mycsv.csv', sep= ';')
print('New df \n',new_df)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `series.apply` I think:

Let's say your column of sets was called `column_of_sets`. Assuming you've already read the csv, now do this to convert back to sets.

```py
df['column_of_sets'] = df['column_of_sets'].apply(eval)
```

I'm taking `eval` from @Cabara's comment. I think it is the best bet.