# Append rows as new columns in another dataframe pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a for loop iterating over rows in an input dataframe. For each row a search is made. The output returns 5 rows and I would like to append these rows as new columns of the input dataframe.

```
    duplicate_materials  
0  [BIAS CUT FABRIC 50 X 1600 MM, RBN20 (000000000001065341)]   
1  [BIAS CUT FABRIC 40 X 1600 MM, RBN20 (000000000001061715)]   
2  [BIAS CUT  FABRIC 40 X 1100 MM, RBN20 (000000000001059946)]  
3  [BIAS CUT FABRIC 40 X 1200 MM, RBN20 (000000000001059947)]   
4  [BIAS CUT  FABRIC 50 X 1300 MM (000000000001005101)]
```

These 5 rows should be appended as 5 new columns to the searched row in the input dataframe. In the following dataframe, the above 5 rows should be listed behind the first column to showcase that this was the result of the search.

```
material_id material_description    duplicate_materials_0   duplicate_materials_1   duplicate_materials_2   duplicate_materials_3   duplicate_materials_4
1   000000000001065341  FABRIC CUT BIAS, RBN20 50 X 1600 MM
```

Edit: Solved by

```
for i, row in results.iterrows():
df_test[f'duplicate_materials_{i}'] = results['duplicate_materials'][i]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the `duplicate_materials` column is of dtype object? This is necessary in order to insert lists into single cells. You can check with this command:

```py
df.dtypes
```

If not, you can set the dtype manually.

```py
df['duplicate_materials'] = df['duplicate_materials'].astype('object')
```

More details: [Python pandas insert list into a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483254/python-pandas-insert-list-into-a-cell)

P.S. You mention using a for-loop to iterate over rows. Maybe this can be avoided by applying the search operation to the whole dataframe.

Comment: Hi, thx for the answer. I have updated the question, as I've concluded that I need 5 new columns instead of 1 large. Can you assist with this?